# How to make this equation bold?

Tags: math-mode, equations, bold

[image]

I tried  `$ \mathbf { 36x^2y+54xy^ 2} $`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you use `\boldmath` before entering math mode. Use grouping to keep the scope of the directive local.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$36x^2y+54xy^2$

{\boldmath $36x^2y+54xy^2$} % use { and } to localize scope of \boldmath

$36x^2y+54xy^2$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `bm` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
I tried $\bm{36x^2y+54xy^2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]